# Angular 2 [ typescript] Updating a model value of parent component UI from a child component UI with json model

Tags: json, typescript, angular, parent-child

How to update the json **'oup'** value from a child component to parent component.
When i try to update the value from child model with output event in to a parent component nothing works.

i given all the details below

Data Handled:

```
   json: [{
      "inp": "hello",
      "oup": "fello"
 }]
```

parent component

```
  // Parent Component
 @Component({
 selector: 'parent',
 template: `
    <div>Parent sharedVarParent: {{sharedVarParent[0].oup}}
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="sharedVarParent[0].oup"/>
    </div>
    <child [(sharedVar)]="sharedVarParent"></child>

      `,
     directives: [ChildComponent]
 })
 export class ParentComponent {
  sharedVarParent =[{
                     "inp": "hello",
                     "oup": "fello"
                    }]

  constructor() { console.clear(); }
 }
```

childcomponent

```
  import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from 'angular2/core'

   // Child Component
  @Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `
    <p>Child sharedVar: {{sharedVar[0].oup}}</p>
    <input [ngModel]="sharedVar[0].oup" (ngModelChange)="change($event)">
    `
   })
   export class ChildComponent {
   @Input() sharedVar: string;
   @Output() sharedVarChange = new EventEmitter();
   change(newValue) {
      console.log('newvalue', newValue)
      this.sharedVar = newValue;
      this.sharedVarChange.emit(newValue);
  }
 }
```

Comment: You are declaring it as a string when really it is `Array<any>` or an array of whatever type has 'inp' and 'oup' properties.  I don't think that's the problem though.  Seems like you are setting the input's model to the 'oup' property of the first element in the array (a string) and emitting that in the change.  Wouldn't that overwrite `sharedVarParent` (an array of objects) with the string value that was entered into the input?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat even after changing the datatype  @Input() sharedVar: Array<any> problem exits, any other suggestion please?. thanks.

Comment: It seems Angular won't acknowledge a nutbox input *for primitives* as associated with a parent. `<input name="parent-notes" [(ngModel)]="parent.notes" />` will work since the primitive value (`notes: string`) is declared off of an object's namespace; but `<input name="child-notes" [(ngModel)]="notes" />` seems to lose the reference to the parents & grandparents. This is not unlike in Angular1.x when you had to use a stupid object just to keep the databinding alive. But how could they have overlooked this in ng2??? I guess you've gotta use the `ControlValueAccessor`.

Answer (score 2):

This looks a bit weird to me. You assign the `fello` value to the input and then emit the updated value. It seems to me you want to emit the changed `sharedVar` instead

```
<input [(ngModel)]="sharedVar[0].oup" (ngModelChange)="change()">
```

```
change() {
  this.sharedVarChange.emit(sharedVar);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution,   it doesn't update the UI model on parent component. Any suggestion to achieve this scenario , thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker to reproduce and investigate? (template https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html)

Comment: I don't know what exactly you try to accomplish but if you modify the same object you don't even need an `@Output()`. The parent will only notify the change if you bind to the value. If you want to notify the parent about the change you can emit **any** value for the parent just to know that the value has changed (without passing the actual value). http://plnkr.co/edit/GV2whC?p=preview

Comment: from your code i understand the purpose of emitting an event and changing the same object. Thanks a lot :). It helps me

Comment: Why you are using Array for this? I tried with a string and is not working. Could you please explain why is working like this?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you send your array as the input instead of just the string?  [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wmZUyNbdfaFqsV2roIpB?p=preview)

Looking at [your sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/PJqvLs?p=preview) there are a few odd things:

1. Your parent input is a one way binding, I don't know if that is confusing you, it's unusual and adds confusion to the question [(fixed)](http://plnkr.co/edit/IueLrtAHLI9y3h0IimuL?p=preview)

   ```
     <input [(ngModel)]="sharedVarParent[0].oup"/>
   ```
2. Since the array is passed by reference as input, there's not really a need for an output of your child component unless you are creating a new array, just use two-way binding on the input in your child and it will update the property on the first object in the shared array [(sample)](http://plnkr.co/edit/QfeUs9jrV5BEzWRG8Zer?p=preview)

   ```
   <input [(ngModel)]="sharedVar[0].oup">
   ```

   3. You're mixing passing the `sharedVar` array as input and outputting a string from the emitter when the child's text box value is updated.  When that happens, the binding in the parent changes `sharedVarParent` to be a string, messing the whole thing up.  When the parent instantiates the child, it sets the input `sharedVar` to the array.  When you type in the child's textbox it outputs a string and the parent changes `sharedVarParent` to be a string, which is then sent as input to the child.  [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QFcjtXXCqfydnEFa05Yg?p=preview)